# How to extract date from text using regex

Tags: python-3.x

```
text = An old structure of a mosque existed at the site until 6 December 1992. Ti su 29 December 2019    

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
                      'November', 'December', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov',
                      'Dec']
months_regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(months) + r')'
       
      
op = re.findall(r'\S*('r'\d{2} '+ months_regex +' \d{4})\S*',text)
print(op)
```

Is there any solution to get 6 December 1992 and 29 December 2019

Answer (score 0):

```
op = re.findall(r'\d{1,2} ' + months_regex + r' \d{4}', text)
```

This will output:

```
['6 December 1992', '29 December 2019']
```